# repeater not giving me new value during editing in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, repeater, edit

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RptrSearchedPhotographer" runat="server" 
            onitemcommand="RptrSearchedPhotographer_ItemCommand" 
            onitemdatabound="RptrSearchedPhotographer_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>   
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="LblContactInfo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ContactInfo")%>'/> 
                <asp:TextBox ID="TxtContactInfo" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ContactInfo") %>' Visible="false" ></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LnkDelete" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id") %>' CommandName="delete">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id") %>' CommandName="edit" EnableViewState ="true">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUpdate" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id") %>' CommandName="update" Visible="false" EnableViewState="true">Update</asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkCancel" runat="server" CommandName="cancel" Visible="false">cancel</asp:LinkButton>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

my .cs code is...

```
if (e.CommandName.Equals("update"))
{
    TextBox DetailNote = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtDetailNote");
    string s = DetailNote.Text;
}
```

But here... It gives the me old value of `s` from textbox. I want new value which is inserted during run time... I googled a lot... but it doesn't work...

Comment: Please post the page load code and Repeater bind code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue, I solved it by adding an "if(!Page.IsPostBack)" before databinding my repeater in the page_load function.